# Visual Studio Code - Target of URI doesn't exist 'package:my_first_flutter_app/main.dart', The neame MyApp isnt a class and imported

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I am brand new to Flutter and I am working on my first ever project which I aptly named "my_first_flutter_app". I'm followng along with the tuturial on the flutter codelab 
and after replacing the contents of `pubspec.yaml` and `analysis_options.yaml` I get the errors listen here in my test file: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8mdK.jpg)

how do I solve these and more importantly how do I prevent them on future projects

I tried  flutter clean Flutter  packages get and Flutter packages upgrade, none of which got rid of any of the errors

Answer (score 0):

First try:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get 
flutter pub upgrade
```

If none of the above works then reload VS code.
`Ctrl+Shift+P`-Windows OR `Cmd+Shift+P`-Mac
`Developer: Reload Window`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Erase everything from that `widget_test.dart` file, paste the below-mentioned code into your `widget_test.dart` file & it will resolve your issue.

```
void main() {}
```