# VScode flutter extension causes a lot of errors on old code

Tags: flutter, dart

I put down a project 1 or 2 years ago that was coded in Dart with the Flutter framework. I just tried to pick it back up but when I installed the Flutter extension in VScode it caused thousands of errors. Does anyone know how to fix this? [image: Here's a picture of the types of errors it's giving]

I've tried downgrading my flutter version but it didn't work.

Comment: We're going to need more info than this to be able to help :) For example, what does the red underline say when you hover over it? Have you tried `flutter run`? What error does that give you?

Comment: Kindly, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76896222/22289437. Kindly, let me know if it works.

Comment: in terminal `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`

Answer (score -1):

run this code in terminal

```
flutter clean
```

then

```
flutter pub get
```

if it still doesn't work run

```
flutter upgrade
```

if still not working let me know in the comments